# Do natural language categories work with utterances not listed on the website?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

The natural language categories on Bixby allow users to use an capsule without specifying the name of the capsule. The RealEstate Category lists two examples:
https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/ref-topics/categories.RealEstate

> 1. How much does an average house cost in {City}?
> 2. Show me 2 bedroom houses in {City} for sale.

Will this work for any utterances in my capsule or only these two?

Answer (score 0):

The examples for each category are what we think are the most likely utterances to be invoked for this category (and are marked as Required) but there are other utterances that are supported for this category.

As the domain expert for your capsule, we anticipate that you will create utterances that create the best user experience and will eventually trigger your capsule through NL Categories.

We are constantly evaluating popular utterances and from time to time we will update the documentation for each category with newer utterances based on user needs.